# How to find-out reason of Chrome: Aw, Snap

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, freeze, mobile-chrome

A [web page](https://feelmy.editorx.io/world/h43?location=50,14&skip=0) randomly crashes only in mobile Chrome with the only message: "Aw, Snap!"
All desktop web browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari) works OK.

I didn't find anything suspicious by DevTools: chrome://inspect/#devices
I looked for console track logs or network. It might be somewhere very deep inside a framework. ([EditorX](https://editorx.com/)).

The moment when it gets frozen changes.
The only that seems consistent is that the page seems to freeze before the Aw, snap!

How to find out what cause of the freeze?

[image]